# The <div> loops automatically and not able to control it

Tags: php, wordpress

Last time i had some problem in my code, by now i have fixed the problem but there is one more problem exixting.
Here in my code, the main `<div>` automatically loops 5 times showing the same list of elements 5 timee. I am unable to find out what has caused the loop. On inspecting the element, i came to know that the main loop i.e. `<div class="row-fluid">` loops for 5 times. Where is the problem and how can i solve it?
Really need help.

Thank u in advance.

```
<?php if ($cat == 2900) { ?>
  <div class="row-fluid">
   <div class="span12 featured-block"> 
    <?php $block1Featured= new WP_Query( 'cat=2900' );
     if ( $block1Featured->have_posts() ) : ?>
      <?php while($block1Featured->have_posts()): $block1Featured->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="span6 ">
        <a class="featured_image" href="<?php the_permalink();?> "target="_blank">
         <?php if ((function_exists('has_post_thumbnail')) && (has_post_thumbnail())  ) { 
           $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id(); 
           $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id,'large');
           $image_url = $image_url[0];
           if(!@getimagesize($image_url)){
           $image_url = "/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/logo2.jpg";
           } 
           $blogurl = get_bloginfo('url'); 
           $image_url = str_replace($blogurl, '', $image_url);
          ?>

           <img src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/thumb.php?src=<?php echo ($image_url); ?>&amp;w=390&amp;h=216&amp;zc=1&amp;q=100" alt="<?php echo the_title(); ?>" />

         <?php }else{ ?> 


           <img src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/thumb.php?src=<?php echo "http://www.nepaljapan.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/logo2.jpg"; ?>&amp;w=390&amp;h=216&amp;zc=1&amp;q=100" alt="<?php echo the_title(); ?>" />


         <?php }?>
        </a>

    <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>" target="_blank">
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2></a>
    <p><?php echo excerpt(37); ?> </p>
    </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php else:  ?>
<p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>

  </div>
  </div>

<?php } ?>

<?php }else{ ?>
//else contents
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Ur snippet looks fine...Can u provide some more code...?

Comment: @Swanishkalwal. Yup i am too unable to find the error with the code. This is a archive-contents page. I wished to show the contents belonging to a particular category in two columns format. But now the whole code loops the number of times as the number of posts. For 5 posts, 5 posts are shown 5 times. And for 6, six times each. The whole contents inside the <?php if ($cat == 2900) { ?> part are looped. What can the possible error be??

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?php

if ($cat == 2900)
    { ?>
  <div class="row-fluid">
   <div class="span12 featured-block"> 
    <?php
    $block1Featured = new WP_Query('cat=2900');
    if ($block1Featured->have_posts()): ?>
      <?php
        while ($block1Featured->have_posts()):
            $block1Featured->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="span6 ">
        <a class="featured_image" href="<?php
            the_permalink(); ?> "target="_blank">
         <?php
            if ((function_exists('has_post_thumbnail')) && (has_post_thumbnail()))
            {
            $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
            $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id, 'large');
            $image_url = $image_url[0];
            if (!@getimagesize($image_url))
            {
            $image_url = "/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/logo2.jpg";
            }

            $blogurl = get_bloginfo('url');
            $image_url = str_replace($blogurl, '', $image_url);
?>

       <img src="<?php
            echo bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/thumb.php?src=<?php
            echo ($image_url); ?>&amp;w=390&amp;h=216&amp;zc=1&amp;q=100" alt="<?php
            echo the_title(); ?>" />

     <?php
            }
            else
            { ?> 


           <img src="<?php
                echo bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/thumb.php?src=<?php
                echo "http://www.nepaljapan.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/logo2.jpg"; ?>&amp;w=390&amp;h=216&amp;zc=1&amp;q=100" alt="<?php
                echo the_title(); ?>" />


         <?php
             } ?>
        </a>

    <a href="<?php
            the_permalink(); ?>" target="_blank">
    <h2><?php
            the_title(); ?></h2></a>
    <p><?php
            echo excerpt(37); ?> </p>
    </div>
    <?php
        endwhile; ?>

    <?php
        wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php
    else: ?>
<p><?php
        _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
<?php
    endif; ?>

  </div>
  </div>

<?php
    } ?>
```